# Remove lines where the first field containing certain strings in linux

Tags: bash

I have a large file with 672,343 rows such like:

```
$ wc -l $GTF
672343 /data1/Annotation/iGenome/Mus_musculus/UCSC/mm10/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf

$ head $GTF
chr1    unknown exon    3214482 3216968 .       -       .       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown stop_codon      3216022 3216024 .       -       .       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown CDS     3216025 3216968 .       -       2       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown CDS     3421702 3421901 .       -       1       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown exon    3421702 3421901 .       -       .       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown CDS     3670552 3671348 .       -       0       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown exon    3670552 3671498 .       -       .       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown start_codon     3671346 3671348 .       -       .       gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15391"; transcript_id "NM_001011874"; tss_id "TSS27105";
chr1    unknown exon    4290846 4293012 .       -       .       gene_id "Rp1"; gene_name "Rp1"; p_id "P17361"; transcript_id "NM_001195662"; tss_id "TSS6138";
chr1    unknown stop_codon      4292981 4292983 .       -       .       gene_id "Rp1"; gene_name "Rp1"; p_id "P17361"; transcript_id "NM_001195662"; tss_id "TSS6138";
```

The unique values in the first field are:

```
$ cat $GTF | cut -f 1 | sort | uniq
chr1
chr10
chr11
chr12
chr13
chr14
chr15
chr16
chr17
chr18
chr19
chr1_GL456211_random
chr1_GL456221_random
chr2
chr3
chr4
chr4_GL456216_random
chr4_GL456350_random
chr4_JH584292_random
chr4_JH584293_random
chr4_JH584294_random
chr5
chr5_GL456354_random
chr5_JH584296_random
chr5_JH584297_random
chr5_JH584298_random
chr5_JH584299_random
chr6
chr7
chr7_GL456219_random
chr8
chr9
chrUn_JH584304
chrX
chrX_GL456233_random
chrY
```

What I wanted to achieve is to remove the lines where the first field containing "_" and output to another file with same format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '$1~/_/{print > "underscores"; next} 1' file
```

prints the records with "_" in the first field to file "underscores", the rest will be printed to stdout (you can redirect to an output file as usual)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep -E '^[^_ ]+ ' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

as much as i like awk, it is great but if you have large files grep will always be faster. Especially if files have 900,000 lines.... imho grep is just a better choice.

if you have large files you should split in a loop that runs multiple processes by ulitizing "&" which is called forking.